# Is there a show only favorite feature? If not, why not?

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

Is there a way to show only questions with tags that I have selected as favorite?

Since this feature obviously doesn't exist, why isn't it implemented?

Comment: You can hide ignored tags... did not see any means to hide questions that does not include a favourite.

Comment: Scenario: someone is interested to answer/see only questions within the range of his favorite tags. When I have selected around 5 tags as favorite, then ignoring all the others will be quite time consuming and contra productive.

Comment: In this case, I am leaving a bounty. However, this bounty is not for someone to come along and say "hey, install my browser plugin" It's here to express how badly I'd like to see this feature in stackexchange. So I hope any attempts at winning it can include the "why" part.

Comment: Very good question, I was going to post a duplicate when I found yours. Hope it gets answered some time.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags